# HDInsight Kafka Cluster not able to access primary storage Blob account

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-storage, azure-hdinsight

I spun Kafka cluster with blob storage (general purpose v1) as primary storage. No other storage attached. However kafka nodes not able to access blob files on same storage. Spark/R clusters can access files on same blob.
I created another kafka cluster but issue is still there. I have provided different container names for each cluster.

Command: `hdfs dfs -ls wasb://elckafka2@demostoragepoc.blob.core.windows.net/`

Error:

> ls: org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: No credentials found
>   for account demostoragepoc.blob.core.windows.net in the configuration,
>   and its container elckafka2 is not accessible using anonymous
>   credentials. Please check if the container exists first. If it is not
>   publicly available, you have to provide account credentials.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Note:** **Private containers in storage accounts that are NOT connected to
>   a cluster**: You can't access the blobs in the containers unless you
>   define the storage account when you submit the WebHCat jobs.

For your understanding, I have created three containers as following;

[image]

If you access containers using HDInsight, you will get the same error message for **private** and **blob** public access level and gives desired output for the **Container** public access level.

[image]

For more details, refer “[HDInsight Storage architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage#hdinsight-storage-architecture)” and “[Hadoop Azure Support: Azure Blob Storage](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-azure/index.html)”.

Comment: I could access HDFS by modifying core-site.xml

Answer (score 0):

In your `core-site.xml`, make sure you have:

```
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>wasb://default@(your account name).blob.core.windows.net</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.azure.account.key.(your account naume).blob.core.windows.net</name>
  <value>(your long hash value from the portal)</value>
</property>
```

Then make sure that this file is propagated to *all* of the nodes in your cluster, and make sure to restart anything that read this file.